# Adding Row Number on SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql-num-rows

Okay this is going be probably very simple, but I've spent 4 hours on this and I'm giving up to ask what I'm missing. I am doing an SQL SELECT statement:

```
"SELECT username, id, Days FROM Users ORDER BY Days DESC";
```

Very simple. But now, when displaying all of my data using this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Days</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . **$row["id"].** "</td><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Days"]. "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

I would like the first one replacing the bold `$row['id']` to be the row number.

I have tried all of the following:

```
SELECT *, number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Days) FROM Users AS rownumber ORDER BY Days;


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Days) AS 'RowNumber', username FROM Users

SELECT  username, Days, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Days) AS 'RowNumber' FROM Users";
```

^^ all of which were things I found on internet. None have worked. Am I missing something blindly obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a programming language, you can keep your SQL simple:

```
"SELECT username, id, Days FROM Users ORDER BY Days DESC";
```

Then process the row number using the programming language:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$rowNumber=0;
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Days</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rowNumber++;
    echo "<tr><td>" . $rowNumber "</td><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Days"]. "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support analytic queries (window functions) like row_number - for that you have to use oracle (if you want something from oracle corp) that does.

I wouldn't use the database for this; modify your front end code to output an incrementing number as it dumps the rows to HTML- this is a task for presentation code, not the sql query

Comment: ..... you're so brilliant. Yes duh. Why did I not think of that, thats easy. Lol thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables.  This normally works:

```
SELECT (@id := @id + 1) as id, username, Days
FROM Users u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @id := 0) params
ORDER BY Days DESC;
```